# Does an Ukrainian need a transit visa in Dubai?

Tags: visas, transit, dubai, ukrainian-citizens

I am an Ukrainina citizen living in Poland. I will be traveling to Thailand but I need to wait at the Dubai airport 9 hours for my next flight back to Poland. I will not be leaving Dubai airport. So in this case do I need a transit visa?

Comment: @Phil, it's not clear from the title, but the question you linked only concerns Ecuadorian/Pakistani citizens en route to Amsterdam, so I don't think it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is maybe, depending oh the nature of your transit. [According to the Emirates Visa Checker:](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/find_visa_requirements/visa_passport_information_results.aspx?NC=UA&NV=Ukraine&AC=PL&AV=Poland&DC=TH&DV=Thailand&TC=AE&TV=United%20Arab%20Emirates&h=78bacb4f3d78510c8c8a774343cb708840c55)

> ## Transit - United Arab Emirates (AE)
>
> #### Visa
>
> Visa required.
>
> #### TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> Holders of confirmed onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.
>   Visa is required for transit between Dubai International Airport (DXB) and Dubai Al Maktoum International (DWC).
>
> #### Visa Issuance:
>
> A 96-hour transit visa can be obtained on arrival at Dubai (DXB), provided:
>
> - transit time is at least 8 hours; and
> - holding onward ticket to a third country; and
> - holding a passport valid for at least 6 months from date of arrival.
>     Visas are only issued as a part of a transit package together with hotel accommodation and airport transfer (paid by passenger).
>
> No visa will be issued on arrival to female passengers under 30 years of age, being nationals of Ukraine.

So, if your transit is less than 24 hours and you don't have to leave the international area of the airport, then you're good. If your transit is longer, then you are OK to get a Visa On Arrival, provided you book a transit package and you are not a young woman (under 30). If you don't have a package or are a young woman, seems you will need to apply in advance.